# Checkbox com dados de uma tabela, gravar em outra

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário com um `checkbox` que paga dados da tabela *mao_obra* e preciso gravar na *detalhe_orcamento*, mas so consigo pegar e gravar o `id` da *mao_obra* mas preciso também do preço e não esta gravando, segue as tabelas e o código que estou usando:

**mao_obra:**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mao_obra` text NOT NULL,
`preco` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

**detalhe_orcamento:**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`orcamento_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`mao_obra_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`preco` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `mao_obra_id` (`mao_obra_id`),
KEY `orcamento_id` (`orcamento_id`)
```

**Codigo:**

```
<?php include("includes/config.php");?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $mao_obra_id        = $_POST['mao_obra_id'];
    $orcamento_id       = $_POST['orcamento_id'];
    $preco              = $_POST['preco'];

    foreach($_POST['mao_obra_id'] as $indice => $valor){
        $inserir = "INSERT INTO detalhe_orcamento1 (mao_obra_id, orcamento_id, preco) VALUE ('".$valor."', '".$orcamento_id."', '".$preco."')" or die(mysql_error());
        $ex = mysql_query($inserir) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
<?php

// consulta do select de Serviços
$selec = "SELECT * FROM mao_obra";
$exec = mysql_query($selec) or die(mysql_error());

// Lista dados do checkbox 
while($dados=mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {

$valor_id       = $dados['id'];
$valor_mao_obra  = $dados['mao_obra'];
$valor_preco     = $dados['preco'];

?>

<form id="form1" action=""enctype=" multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input style="margin-left:30px" name="mao_obra_id[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $valor_id ?>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $valor_mao_obra ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="<?php echo $valor_preco ?>" /><?php echo $valor_preco ?>
 <?php  }?>
 <input type="text" name="orcamento_id" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Adicionar Orçamento" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

O `id` é gravado certo pelo `checkbox` selecionado, mas o preço só grava o primeiro.

Comment: Pode postar o formulário?

Comment: Se tem vários campos com o mesmo nome preço, creio que deve usar `[]`, ou seja `name="preco[]"`. Mas não está muito claro qual é o seu HTML... só tem esse form com 3 inputs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exemplo de como recuperar esses dados:**

A variável `$checkbox` é um array com `id` e `value` para que seja mostrado os valores. O ponto chave é que o `id` fica fácil recuperar, enquanto o value tem que usar uma outra técnica de `nome + id` sendo que para o `id` de valor `1` tem um `input hidden` `valores_1`.

***Assim:***

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]"      value="1">
<input type="hidden"   name="valores_1" value="1.5">
```

Na hora da recuperação fica fácil, porque se o `id` de valor `1` for recuperado é só você escrever `$_POST['valores_'.id]` ou seja, `$_POST['valores_'.1]` para recuperar o valor referente o *`id = 1`*.

***Exemplo completo:***

```
<?php
    $checkbox = array(array("id" => 1, "value" => 1.50),
                      array("id" => 2, "value" => 2.50),
                      array("id" => 3, "value" => 3.50));
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="roto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
    <?php foreach($checkbox as $value): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>">
        <input type="hidden"   name="valores_<?php echo $value['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $value['value'];?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['id'])):
            foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value):
                echo $value . ' - ' . $_POST['valores_'.$value];
                echo '<br>';
            endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Se você precisar recuperar mais valores é a mesma lógica empregada de `nome + id` aonde id seria o ponto chave de recuperação dos outros valores.

***Html gerado:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="roto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]"      value="1">
        <input type="hidden"   name="valores_1" value="1.5">

        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]"      value="2">
        <input type="hidden"   name="valores_2" value="2.5">

        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]"      value="3">
        <input type="hidden"   name="valores_3" value="3.50">

        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Escolhendo os valores 1 e 3 sairá o resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Seguindo no seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:***

```
<?php include("includes/config.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){       
        $orcamento_id = $_POST['orcamento_id'];
        foreach($_POST['mao_obra_id'] as $indice => $valor){
            $preco   = $_POST['preco'.$valor];
            $inserir = "INSERT INTO detalhe_orcamento1 
            (mao_obra_id, orcamento_id, preco) VALUE ('".$valor."', '".$orcamento_id."', '".$preco."')" 
            or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query($inserir) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }   
    // consulta do select de Serviços
    $selec = "SELECT * FROM mao_obra";
    $exec = mysql_query($selec) or die(mysql_error());
    // Lista dados do checkbox 
?>

<form id="form1" action="" enctype=" multipart/form-data" method="post">
<?php
    while($dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
        $valor_id        =  $dados['id'];
        $valor_mao_obra  =  $dados['mao_obra'];
        $valor_preco     =  $dados['preco'];

?>
    <input style="margin-left:30px" name="mao_obra_id[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $valor_id ?>"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $valor_mao_obra ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="preco<?php echo $valor_id ?>" value="<?php echo $valor_preco ?>" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $valor_preco ?>
<?php 
    } 
?>
    <input type="text" name="orcamento_id" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Adicionar Orçamento" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Obs:** *eu não tenho como debugar o seu código, então não sei se o mesmo está perfeito. O meu exemplo se pode copiar e colar em um outro arquivo que funciona perfeitamente e pode seguir como tutorial.*

Comment: Harry não sei como agradecer muito obrigado, a meses estou tentando solucionar esse problema e não tinha conseguido entender, agora ficou claro como funciona, testei aqui e esta funcionando corretamente, mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Comment: Ola Henrry, sobre o código que você me ajudou, esta perfeito, mas me deparei com um problema no formulário de update, poderia me ajudar como fazer para resgatar os checkbox inseridos, tenho que criar outra pergunta? Outra duvida é sobre o Stackoverflow, tenho que me registrar para aparece meu nome igual ao seu, eu só fiz o login com a conta do gmail, Obrigado

Comment: @user3715576 tipo se quer que o form na hora de carregar te mostre qual está selecionado ? é isso ?

Comment: Isso mesmo para uma eventual edição de itens

Comment: seria uma coisa assim: `<?php $value['id'] == 1 ?' checked="checked"':'';?>` se não acha melhor abrir outra questão detalhando e colocando código de exemplo igual a essa?